The PS and AI show different color under the same color mode (CMYK)
I began working with a photoshop file (preset CMYK color mode) and brought the result (as CMYK jpeg) into AI (preset CMYK color mode), but the color is totally different. Shifting to GPU/CPU view mode doesn't help as well, the three outcomes are different too. Anyone knows how to make the AI color mode the same as PS?

Not enough info to help. Suggest taking screenshot of you color management settings

Check that the colour settings in both Illustrator and Photoshop match.  You can use Adobe Bridge to synchronize the colour settings across both applications.

Also, for more information check the Adobe help page on Keeping colors consistent
